# Does the GitLab runner configuration file support comments?

Tags: ansible, gitlab

Does the [GitLab Runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#configuration-file) configuration file support comments? I also don't see comments mentioned in the [Advanced Configuration doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html).

I need comments to use [Ansible's `blockinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/blockinfile_module.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab uses [TOML (Tom's Obvious, Minimal Language)](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml#user-content-comment). The TOML format supports multiple forms for comments.

```
# This is a full-line comment
key = "value"  # This is a comment at the end of a line
another = "# This is not a comment"
```